# Creature that feeds off personal attachment?

Tags: myth-identification, mythical-creatures

New here. I did search for this in several different forms and places. Not sure if this is the right place, but I saw similar questions here, so I'll give it a shot.

I'm looking for the word for a demon, or just an evil creature, that feeds off of person-to-item attachment.

If I need to be more specific, this creature will literally eat the attachment off of an item. Given a prized possession, say a charm passed down to you from your mother, it will eat the history (therefore eating part of your relationship?) so that it's just some old piece of metal your mom found. A souvenir from that trip you took a few years ago? Just something cheap and pretty you found at a store. You don't lose any memories, but the memories no longer matter.

If this does not exist already, what's the closest existing thing, and what new name would it be given?

(Sorry if some of this doesn't make sense - I'm happy to answer any questions, or edit/remove the question if there's a problem! One name I've been suggested is "attachment distorter".)

Comment: Not really the same and definitely not Myth, but the question reminds me of Maja from Adventure Times.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure I know of an creature/entity that meets your conditions, there are a number of [mythological creatures](https://listverse.com/2014/01/21/10-ancient-legends-about-dreams/) that eat and/or feed of dreams such as the Baku but they are not eating memories, well maybe they eat the memories of your dreams and/or nightmares.

I know there was a book [The Memory Eater](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/098566620X) that might be closer to what you are after.